# Fullscreen button of Video inside WebView not working

Tags: java, android, video, youtube, fullscreen

I'm trying to implement a subclass of WebChromeClient in order to have a working fullscreen button on youtube embed video links (ex: https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ) inside a WebView.

I basically simplified [this repo](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView), here are some snippets:

**VideoWebChromeClient:**

```
public class VideoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private boolean isVideoFullscreen = false;
    private View activityNonVideoView;
    private ViewGroup activityVideoView;
    private View videoViewContainer;
    private CustomViewCallback videoCallback;
    private Window videoWindow;

    public VideoWebChromeClient(View activityNonVideoView, ViewGroup activityVideoView, Window window) {
        this.activityNonVideoView = activityNonVideoView;
        this.activityVideoView =  activityVideoView;
        this.videoWindow = window;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        Log.w("ENTER FULLSCREEN");
        videoCallback = callback;
        videoViewContainer = view;
        videoWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        activityNonVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        activityVideoView.addView(videoViewContainer, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        activityVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isVideoFullscreen = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (!isVideoFullscreen) {
            return;
        }
        Log.w("EXIT FULLSCREEN");
        activityVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        activityVideoView.removeView(videoViewContainer);
        activityNonVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        videoViewContainer = null;
        videoCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        isVideoFullscreen = false;
    }

    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        onHideCustomView();
        return isVideoFullscreen;
    }
  }
```

**WebViewActivity**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public static final String WEB_VIEW_URL_EXTRA = "URL";
    private boolean loadedFirstURL = true;
    private VideoWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;

    @Bind(webview)
    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(provideLayoutId());
        String url = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(WEB_VIEW_URL_EXTRA);

        // Check if URL is YouTube / Vimeo
        if (RegexHelper.isVideoURL(url)){
            // Allow Fullscreen
            final View defaultLayout = findViewById(R.id.defaultLayout);
            final View fullscreenLayout = findViewById(R.id.fullscreenLayout);
            mWebChromeClient = new VideoWebChromeClient(defaultLayout, (ViewGroup) fullscreenLayout, getWindow());
            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

            // Block external links
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (loadedFirstURL) {
                        loadedFirstURL = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (!mWebChromeClient.onBackPressed())
            {
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                }
                else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It works correctly on **KitKat** but not on **Nougat** (I have only those two devices to test on): when I tap the fullscreen button it sometimes goes into fullscreen, but most times it "flashes" and stays not-fullscreen.

And then, when it's actually in fullscreen mode, the button to exit fullscreen doesn't work (`onHideCustomView` is not called at all)

You can see that I put logs and noticed that when the "flash" happens, `onHideCustomView` is actually called right after `onShowCustomView` (`"ENTER FULLSCREEN"` then immediately `"EXIT FULLSCREEN"`), I don't understand why.

Thanks a lot if anyone can point me towards a solution

Comment: Just an opinion based on my experiencing and research: forget webview to deal with youtube videos: laying on proper Youtube API you will free yourself of every week's surprising update.

Comment: @statosdotcom yes I'd like it of I could just open it in the YouTube app but I can't since the goal is to just display one video and to avoid suggesting others.

Comment: Maybe the API can offer some configuration for you, allowing some fine tuning. I think you should have a look on it. Best luck.

Comment: @statosdotcom : I didn't really find a solution so I just ended up doing it in a simpler way: I display my whole webView fullscreen, and since I use YT "embed" url it looks like I want it to! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Many thanks for your consideration with me: you've done it by yourself, so no need to thank me at all. It's nice you returned here with your goals because this can make people (like me) learn with your efforts. Thank you and congratulations. Keep it up man. Best luck.

Comment: @statosdotcom always good to find nice people on the interwebs ! Best luck to you too :)

Comment: God bless (()).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue but I fixed it after spending hours on it.

All you have to do is set the UserAgent String of a KitKat device. And that is it!

```
private String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 5 Build/_BuildID_) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36";
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

This will fix all the weird functioning of **onShowCustomView()** and **onHideCustomView()** on newer devices.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This is more of a workaround but thank you, I'll keep that in mind if I work on this again.